# Exit in Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Framework based application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to Exit from Windows Phone 7 Silverlight based Application.

I read that we can do that by using NavigationService.GoBack()

But i do not want to Execute the next line of code after i call "NavigationService.GoBack()"

Is there a Exit method in Windows Phone 7 Silverlight application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Exit windows phone 7 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492053/how-to-exit-windows-phone-7-app)

Answer (score 1):

That's not completely true. You can go back to a previous page in your app by using NavigationService.GoBack(), though you can't exit the app by using that.

There's a possibility to exit the application by firing a fatal exception, though it's not recommended. There aren't many apps that do really exit through code, however games do enable exiting. Please review the reason why you want to exit the application because most of the time it doesn't fit in the metro style of apps.

Comment: Is there any Alternative to it so that NavigationService.GoBack(),  will not throw an exception. I am using Silverlight Framework and not XNA Framework.

Comment: As I said, why do you want to programmatically exit the application?

Comment: I want to Exit the Application if there is no Internet Connection on the Phone. I am checking for Network and then exiting.        bool hasNetworkConnection =
             NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.None;
            if (!hasNetworkConnection)
           NavigationService.GoBack()

Comment: I would recommend showing a message instead. The user won't know the reason why the app was closed and has a feeling it crashed, after a couple of crashes the user will be sure to uninstall that 'crappy' app. Even though your intention was to close it, because it's unusable without internet, the user will not have that feeling.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
while(NavigationService.BackStack.Count() > 0)
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just exit your function:

```
 NavigationService.GoBack();
 return;
```

Note that NavigationService.GoBack() will throw an exception (you're not supposed to call it when the backstack is empty), so the next line of code wouldn't be executed anyway. Not sure it will pass marketplace certification.

Comment: Is there any Alternative to it, so that it will not throw an exception

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx

Answer (score 0):

as i know in the windows phone 8 there's an API

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

but i don't know if WP7 have it or not

try it and tell us