# Close a WP7 application programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, exit, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Phone 7 close application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659195/windows-phone-7-close-application)

How do I programmatically close a WP7 application?

Comment: Please read this: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-exit-application.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can always call an exit by doing this at your landing page use this code on click of your application back button:

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

This will remove back entries from the stack, and you will press a back button it will close the application without any exception.

Comment: Even though I'm almost 2 years late now, I'll accept this answer instead as it seems to work indeed.

Answer (score 8):

Acknowledging known solutions to provide "Exit" buttons, currently I do not see a compelling reason to implement an "exit" from a WP7 application.

The platform is fully capable of managing closure of apps. The more apps don't provide an exit, the quicker users will become accustomed to not thinking about app house keeping, and let the platform manage it.

The user will just navigate their device using start, back, etc.

If the user wants out of the current app to go do something else quickly - easy - they just hit start.

.Exit(), whilst available for xna, really isn't required anymore either. There was a cert requirement during CTP that games had to provide an exit button. This is now gone.

Non game apps never had the need to implement this.

The more this topic's discussed (and it really has been given a good run around the block), the more the indicators to me suggest there is no need to code an exit.

It should also be mentioned the app cert reqts are specific that apps should not have unhandled exceptions.

Comment: It's generally advisable to try and fit in with the platform than fight it. Users relate well to consistency.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't really a *good way* to do it. There is a [nice explanation/overview of your options here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx).

For short, if this is a Silverlight app (not XNA), it is not supported. You can simply throw an unhandled exception, and the app will quit. I wouldn't recommend that, it seems like a hack and a rather crude way of doing it.

[Here is a way to make it look nicer,](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/22/How-to-Quit-a-WP7-Silverlight-Application.aspx) but at the end of the day it still throws an exception. I don't know if the application certification process looks at whether you are throwing unhandled exceptions, but I guess it could be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the links! It helped! I decided to remove the Quit button after all. :D

Comment: Thats fully wrong. Since first release, you have to leave the application by using `NavigationSerice.Back()` command. If you are not in root you can use it as long as the app is closed. But other stuff is hacked and not recommended, sorry.

Comment: I think microsoft checks for unhandled exceptions and refuses the app that has it.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest thing to do is simulate back from your root/home page. I'm guessing this is exactly what apps (those which have quit button) like Fruit Ninja do.

```
if ( NavigationService.CanGoBack )  
{  
    NavigationService.GoBack();  
}
```

Btw, above snippet works for a silverlight app.

Comment: thats the only real answer. I could not believe the other answer with 4 upvotes to thow exceptions or break the application.

Comment: it always gives false with me on CanGoBack

Comment: It only follow stepwise within the stack entries. If you want an exit button than you must remove all the entries from stack.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to exit the application is calling the exit function of the Game class of Microsoft Xna framework.

For example:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game();
game.Exit();
```

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me..

Comment: its for xna only, it will not work on a silverlight app

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void exitBUtton_ONclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("ExitAppException");
     }
```