# Windows Phone 7 - Deactivation?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to easily deactivate an application?  The only way I know how to truly deactivate an application is to hit the back button until I get to the main screen.

Right now my app has several pages and if I want to close it I have to hit the back button over and over again.

Is there a way in code that I can just deactivate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not - there's no clean way of forcing an app to exit.

You could throw an exception, of course - but that's far from clean, and may prevent your app from being approved.

It's a somewhat bizarre state of affairs IMO, and I wouldn't be surprised to see it change over time - but for the moment, that's all there is.

(That means if your app has an EULA, you can't even have a "decline" button... the only way the user can exit is by hitting back/start/search.)

Comment: that was my understanding as well.  I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything.  I hope it does change, because it does affect the user experience.  Thanks for clarifying this for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can close the app, if you hit the Start button as well. There is no other chance to close/exit a Windows Phone 7 application from code.

Comment: Pressing the start button causes the app to be tombstoned. The same as if you pressed the search button, opened some of the Launchers, opened a toast notification and many more situations.

Answer (score 1):

My view at the moment is I don't believe an exit function is necessary in WP7 apps. I explained why in these 2 Questions if you'd like to know why.

[Close a WP7 application programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338589/close-a-wp7-application-programatically)

[Windows Phone 7 close application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659195/windows-phone-7-close-application)

With that said there are some things you might like to consider. First is offering your user a way to quickly navigate back to your home page.

[Want to "reset" an app but how to deal with backstack pages?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/7cbb9e11-3432-4db8-b87d-60d23ade4da9)

[Removing a page from the navigation stack](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/210992dc-04e1-4ae6-b808-13cbf33db318)

[Can the navigation history be cleared](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/226d6ea4-0a69-47fa-bb9c-4d41080e8d97/)

There are several solutions to this which have been posted.

Also recently, code has been released that allows you to build this in with a bit more simplicity.

[Solving Circular Navigation in Windows Phone Silverlight Applications](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx)

Using one of these implementations your user can "back out" of your app with 2 actions if they want to.

Mindful, that if they want to navigate away from your app immediately, they need only press the Start key.

I think we'll have to wait and see how this situation plays out. As noted it is a bit different to what we're accustomed to, but I'm prepared to give the idea a chance and review the pros/cons of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could call NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() this will remove all other pages so the next time the back button is hit the application will exit.