# Removing the MainPage.xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I have been looking into this for awhile and have had no real luck.

My project consists of a Login page that happens to be the MainPage.xaml.

The users who will be using this App should not be able to go back to the page with the Windows mobile 7 back button.

My Second Page is Called afterLoginMenu.xaml, i want it so that when the user presses the back button from the second page it will close the application never showing the login page again.

Is this Possible? and if so How?

Thank you In advance!

Comment: Are you targeting Mango? (7.1)? You could try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx.

Comment: No, i am not targeting mango on this one.

Comment: That's a valid answer to the problem wilmel. You should write it as such, perhaps with a piece of code sample. And clarify that it's not really possible to do for NoDo.

Comment: Keeano: Without Mango, you can't control the navigation flow. So your have to design a architecture that allows you to avoid this problem, or upgrade to Mango. (Obviously your app won't get certified with the current "problem")

Comment: 1. ovveriding the back button - as explained here: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/03/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-3-the-back-button-paradigm/ 2. close the application programatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338589/close-a-wp7-application-programatically or http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/22/How-to-Quit-a-WP7-Silverlight-Application.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're using mango, you have two options: Display a `Popup` which has your login information (like the Facebook app) or have both the login and 'main page' on the same page, and change the `Visibility` of the page controls depending on whether or not the user needs to log in.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot>
<Grid x:Name="LoginGrid" Visibility="Visible">
...</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="AuthenticatedGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
...</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thank you For your advice, one thing right now. i tried using a Popup but i couldn't get it to show at the start of MainPage.xaml. How Would i do that?

Comment: yes. here is my .xaml code. <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Popup x:Name="loginPopUpwindow" Height="250" Width="300" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsOpen="True">
                <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,160,0,0" Name="loginTextBlock" Text="Login" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474"/>
            </Popup>
            <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,160,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" />
        </Grid>

Comment: Rather than putting that code inside the <Popup> tags, try putting it inside <Popup.Child>. I've only created the Popup I use for my app in code-behind.

Comment: like <Popup><Popup.Child><TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,160,0,0" Name="loginTextBlock" Text="Login" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474"/> </Popup.Child></Popup>

Comment: Hey, Thank you agian @willmel. I was doing it right but something i cant put my finger on wasn't right so started over and its working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

after create your Login popup control, do something like this:

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (someVariable == 0)
        {
            myPopup = new Popup() { IsOpen = true, Child = new Login() };


            someVariable = 1; //this will be a global value, so the popup wouldn't open again when back key is pressed
        }


    }
```