# How to go to main menu on a button click in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, navigation, onclick

I have a button in the main page and on the click of it i want to exit the app and return to the phone's main menu page. My concern is that i cannot use CancelEventArgs for button_click event and another concern is that this is the first page in theNavigation stack, so Navigetion.goBack is false. Suggestions and help are welcome.

```
private void btnDeclineClick(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       exitApplication();
    }

 public  void exitApplication()
    {
        try
        {
            NavigationService.CanGoBack.Equals(true);
            if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log(TAG, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is clicking your button (which is on the main page) somehow easier for the user than clicking the hardware back button?

Comment: Actually the button is a decline button..so when thats clicked the app Should exit.. Since there is a button called decline there are chances that the user will use it right. coz ther is an Accept button too that has other functionality.

Comment: My advice would be to get rid of the *Decline* button, just have one *Accept* button. If the user does not want to accept your terms she can press the hardware back key to exit the app.

Comment: Am thinking of using a customized exception handling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically exiting the application is not supported and against the certification requirements. I agre with Praetorian that you should just not have a Decline button or have it simply cover the application UI with some non-interactive content.

The only supported mechanisms for exiting the application are for the user to press the back button or navigating forward out of the application using the home/windows button or any launcher and then being killed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Is this are you facing problem of exiting application programmatically ??
If yes you can do that without worrying which page user into currently

For exiting programmatically you can check [this my another post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338589/close-a-wp7-application-programatically/8005201#8005201).

Comment: We already used this.. but.. Since our App is going to be launched on the marketplace this is not allowed. so u cannot use xna framework element when u r releasing ur app on marketplace. Its not acceptable.

Comment: In my guess, it may be acceptable by Microsoft. Are you using any non linear navigation between pages(Circular page navigation) without using proper non linear navigation class?

Comment: Can you give some details on the comment you got using the xna framework by Ms ??

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx refer that article its really good. and there is link to download the application guidelines go through it once it will clear all ur doubts.

Comment: I went through that link, It seems that, your using any non linear navigation between pages(Circular page navigation) without using proper non linear navigation class.

Comment: Anyway, there is a tweak that you can remove the previous page entries when you want to exit and let user to press back and exit the application. you can remove page entries when your application at the stage of the exit (you can do so by code while ((NavigationService.CanGoBack))
            {
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }) And you can let the user to click the back button and exit the application.

Comment: I have used it.. thr are no previous page entries.. the Navigation.CanGoBack become false. so that is not working too..