# How to exit from the application in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I want to quit the application from the Application page, on click of a button.
Please guide me to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to close a Silverlight Application from code, but you will find a small loophole in this under the page i linked in.

[Possibly you will find the answer here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338589/close-a-wp7-application-programatically)

If it is an XNA then you can Call Game.Exit()

Answer (score 5):

You can't quit the application. That is controlled by the OS.

Comment: you mean there no way to close my application ?

Comment: No, you can't close the application. There is one way and that is to throw an unhandled exception but, DONT even think of doing that because that would get your app rejected. What is it exactly that you are trying to do? If you elaborate, we may be able to suggest a work-around