# Exit app in Windows Phone 7

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7

I want close my app using code in Windows Phone 7.1
(when clicked on button, the app closes).
In Windows Phone 8 it's easy:

```
Application.Current.Terminate()
```

But how to do this on WP 7 (using VB.Net) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exit from the application in WP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681484/how-to-exit-from-the-application-in-wp7)

Comment: there are many thread discussing this thing on SO. Please consider searching before asking!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know VB.NET syntax but you can get idear from following C# syntax.

You can always close app by doing this at your landing page. Use this code on click of your application back button:

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

This will remove all back entries from the stack, and when you will press a back button, it will exit the application without any exception.