# How to exit Windows Phone App without back

Tags: windows-phone-7, exit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close a WP7 application programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338589/close-a-wp7-application-programatically)

I want to show to my user that he needs Internet connection for the application using MessageBox. When he clicks OK I like to exit the application without using BackButton
Here is the code

```
try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Потребна е Интернет конекција");
               if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
               {
                   while (NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
                      NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                    //base.OnBackKeyPress(new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs());
                   NavigationService.GoBack();
                }



            });


        }
```

However, the app is not exiting it is trying to connect to the web service

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @willmel your user experience isn't in line with that of Windows Phone. Peter Torr of Microsoft has an excellent, if a little old, [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx) on why this is a bad idea (from a user experience perspective) and how to design your interfaces so that it's not necessary to exit an application programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Apps cannot be programatically closed, and won't get past certification. You'll need to rethink your User Experience.

For example, you could prompt the same message, and disable all the controls of the app so the user leaves the app themselves via the back-button.

Additionally, keep in `MessageBoxResult.None`, which is the result of pressing the hardware back-button to dismiss a dialog. (it doesn't look like you're handling it in your code)

Comment: Apps can be closed in program. XNA has exit method and in Silverlight you can throw an exception, as you mentioned, it won't pass the cert.

Comment: Good point on XNA... I separate XNA into 'games' rather than 'apps', since they have different marketplace certification requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend relying on catching an error for what you are trying to do. You would have many false positives. The phone has an API to determine if the network if available. In your MainPage.xaml.cs do the following:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No network! Try again later.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Logic that would happen if they had connection, maybe you show controls 
        // here that might not be displayed w/o a connection
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm intrested about the moment when the user will click on OK button from the message box. I like to exit the app, however the app is still trying to connect to the web service

Comment: I understand. What I'm suggesting is to not do that. Instead, check for network connectivity when the user navigates to the page (MainPage) and tell them there is no connectivity. Allow them to exit the app after, or send them to a login screen if you have one. Do not send them out of the app. This is not recomended.