# How to Exit From the Application in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Phone 7 close application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659195/windows-phone-7-close-application)

How to Exit from the app when user presses Back Key Button from Device??

Thanks,
Balaram.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? Do you want to ext the app on back key press from an arbitrary page or from the start page? In the latter case the OS does that automatically.

Comment: if you are a game, there's an API call to exit, but for apps, you generally let the OS handle it for you.

Comment: Please read this: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-exit-application.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really want to do Exit, you can throw an unhandled exception and your app will close. **But it is a very bad thing to do!**

Comment: Your suggesting they *purposely* throw an exception??

Comment: Yes, that's what he's suggesting, as it's the only way to really "exit" a Phone SL app.

Comment: Well I suppose if your considering it an "answer". But this is far from a solution. Keep in mind "Unhandled Exceptions" results in failing certification according to Microsoft Guidelines.

Comment: Ofc it would fail certification, cuz they said: NO EXIT buttons in SL apps. But it's the only way to really "Exit"

Comment: The only answer to this one is 
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

This is handled automatically for you.

<slightly simplfied answer>
The back button gives access to the navigation system within the application.  If there are previous pages to return to, the back button will take you back to the most recent previous page.  If there are no previous pages, the application will exit.  You don't need to do anything to make it exit.
</slightly simplfied answer>

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
void Exit()
{
    while (NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    base.OnBackKeyPress(new CancelEventArgs());
}
```

Best of luck to you.

Comment: Please read: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-exit-application.html

Answer (score 0):

This is handled automatically for you if you are on the first page the app began with.

Now you can override the [backkey press event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28VS.92%29.aspx) but you run the risk of not passing certification when you submit the app. The backkey is meant to go to the previous page of the application, and exit if its the first page. Microsoft does have exceptions to this, such as pausing a game, but other than that it has to stick to its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call an exit by doing this at your landing page use this code on click of your application back button:

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

This will remove back entries from the stack, and you will press a back button it will close the application without any exception.