# Windows phone: close the app after click on a button

Tags: windows-phone-7, exit

How can I close my app after a button click? I mean in:

```
    private void chiudi_app(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){

    }
```

I've tried a lot of things founded around the web (like Application.Exit() and other things), but without success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 close application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659195/windows-phone-7-close-application)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In WP7 there is no API to exit your app. But you can create an ExitException

```
public class ExitException :Exception {}
```

and throw it where ever you want to quit.

```
throw new ExitException();
```

Comment: it doesn't close the app and throw an "exception not managed"