# Kill an app when return from WebBrowseTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I made a small app, and I have a button than pin to start a web blog via a xaml, so when the tile is pin, it goes to the xaml, which automatically redirect to the blog by `WebBrowserTask`. MY problem is that if they press the back button from the web page, they go to the xaml, and I want them to go directly to the start menu, so I'm looking for a way to kill the app when they return from the

the xaml code is

```
private void WebPages_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
            task.Uri = new Uri(NavigationContext.QueryString["uri"]);
            task.Show();
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No URI was passed to the app.");
        }
```

}

I don't know if this is possible, but if someone knows i'll be pleased. Thanks

Comment: I have no clue about  what you're asking and/or explaining to us

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Windows Phone 7 close application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659195/windows-phone-7-close-application) to kill an app, you may want to try this solution :

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
 while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
 {
     NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
 }
}
```

Comment: that will clear the back stack.  without calling NavigationService.GoBack(); afterwards, I'm not sure if the app will close.

Comment: If you set this code on the NavigatedTo, it will clear the back stack as you said, then the user manually click GoBack => back stack is empty => the app close

Answer (score 0):

You may want to load your blog inside a WebBrowser control rather than running a WebBrowseTask.  Then, clear the back stack if need be in the OnBackKeyPress event.  If you open a WebBrowserTask, the user will have to hit back to resume your app and then hit back again to return to the start menu.  You won't be able to exit your app automatically after resuming.  Its against the marketplace guidelines.