# How to exit or quit my Windows Phone 8 app programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application.

1. How can I exit or quit programmatically (through code) from my Windows Phone 8 app?
2. What are the various ways in which I can programmatically (through code) exit or quit from my Windows Phone 8 app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 close application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659195/windows-phone-7-close-application)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In WP8 there's a new API which lets you terminate the application:

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

By calling the method your app will immediatelly terminate. However the `Application_Closing` event won't be called, and `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` dictionary won't be automatically persisted.

So if you have data hanging around in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings that you don't want to lose then it's wise to save it:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

Also the method should not be misused. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.application.terminate(v=vs.105).aspx for more info for legitimate use cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (((PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual).CanGoBack)
{
    ((PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual).RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I modified this to use `while (NavigationService.CanGoBack) NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()`. Is there a difference? It seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8.1, the method has been renamed to

```
Application.Current.Exit();
```