# How to terminate windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to exit my app when the user press back button. I have used Hardware Pressed events to navigate between pages.
When I navigated to the first page  where no Hardware Button press event is used and press back button it goes back to the Menu Screen and not getting terminated as shown in image

[image]

Need help.

Comment: Already asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052311/how-to-programatically-through-code-to-exit-or-quit-from-windows-phone-8-app

Comment: This is windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also faced the same problem but by using the following piece of code

`Application.Current.Exit()`

the application shuts down properly.

Comment: This will shut the application down, but not properly.

Answer (score 4):

This is generally not recommended. Think hard about why you want to do this and if it really makes sense. Barring recovering from a failure it usually doesn't. The expected behavior is for the app to work nicely with the process lifetime code. There is typically no downside to keeping the app suspended, and it is much more efficient to resume from suspension than to restart completely. The user can use the built-in options to explicitly close the app if desired.

That said, you can call [Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.exit.aspx) .

Comment: A lot of marketplace apps that i tested today are removed from the history when the back button is pressed in the first page. Leave the app in the history (just like the posted screenshot), in Suspended mode is the correct approach?

Comment: Yes. Leave the app in the history and let the OS and user manage actually closing the app. That is much friendlier both to the user experience and to power usage.

Comment: @Rob Caplan, since you said friendlier "to the user experience", I am sure many users consider the system to be unfriendly for keeping an application hanging around after the user does not need it. This is not the place to discuss it, but saying it is how the **users** want it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to make the back button react the same as WP8 on WP8.1. In `public App()`:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#endif
```

and in the same scope as `App()`:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
#endif
```