# Close Windows Phone 8 App Programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've a Windows Phone 8 Application and with a button click, I want to ask user something like "Are you sure?" and if answer is yes(ok) then application will be closed.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything except "Application.Terminate()" but seems this is not the right way how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exit or quit my Windows Phone 8 app programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052311/how-to-exit-or-quit-my-windows-phone-8-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible to do this using `System.Windows.Application.Current.Terminate()` as Nikita says it is not recommended to offer such a functionality. Here's an excerpt from the [Windows Phone Guidelines on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx):

> Don't include Close buttons or offer users other ways to terminate
>   your app in its UI. Users should feel confident that the system is
>   managing their apps for them. The system can terminate apps
>   automatically to ensure the best system performance and reliability,
>   and users can choose to close apps using gestures on Windows or
>   through the Task Switcher on Windows Phone.

The user should only be able to Close an app using the home or back-button.

Comment: @Thomas the link is invalid , pls check

Comment: @Diga I think it is reasonable as those restrictions aim to provide similar UX on all apps (same thing with back-buttons). What you can do is ask a user if he wants to quit the app when he tries to close it using the back button.

Comment: I saw some guys using a while loop for closing. What do you think about this?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that. Are you talking about deliberately crashing the app?