# WL.App.close doesnt work in a windows phone8 mobilefirst 6.3 app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst

Im trying to close a mobilefirst 6.3 hybrid app, that is running on android and ios, but in windows phone the `WL.App.close` method doesnt do anything, how can i close a hybrid mobilefirst app in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

The `WL.App.close` API method is in fact not supposed to do anything really anymore even in iOS and Android, as it is no longer considered a best practice in those platforms to force-close an application. It is an action that the user must do.

It looks to me like the same is applied to Windows Phone: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn148258(v=vs.105).aspx

You may be able to do the following, though: [How to exit or quit my Windows Phone 8 app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052311/how-to-exit-or-quit-my-windows-phone-8-app-programmatically)

Comment: And, is there a way to minimize de app with a mobilefirst first function? I didnt saw nothing for this in the documentation. Which will be the best practice for the back functionality in the first page on the stack?

Comment: MobileFirst is not a UI framework, so no, it's not possible via MobileFirst. What you're looking for can be achieved using normal JavaScript.